# Consuming Sharepoint web service using SOAP

Tags: java, web-services, soap

In my Netbeans, after clean and successful build, when running my program the following message appears:

```
SEVERE: Injection on a method requires a void return type
 symbol: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceRef
 location: public com.microsoft.schemas.sharepoint.soap.directory.GetUserInfoResponse$GetUserInfoResult pt.marinha.ditic.dss.NewWebServiceFromWSDL.getUserInfo(java.lang.String)
SEVERE: Injection on a method requires a void return type
 symbol: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceRef
 location: public com.microsoft.schemas.sharepoint.soap.directory.GetUserInfoResponse$GetUserInfoResult pt.marinha.ditic.dss.NewWebServiceFromWSDL.getUserInfo(java.lang.String)
SEVERE: Annotations processing failed for file:/C:/Users/m9351234/Documents/NetBeansProjects/SharePointWS/SharePointWS-war/build/web/
INFO: WS00018: Webservice Endpoint deployed

INFO: WEB0671: Loading application [SharePointWS-war] at [/SharePointWS-war]
INFO: SharePointWS-war was successfully deployed in 1.480 milliseconds.
```

What could it mean?

*I dont know how to handle the usergroups methods in Java.*

Answer (score 2):

Going by the error message, it seems you're trying to use some Dependency Injection framework, that only supports member injection on methods that have a void return type, where as yours is returning an object instance.

Comment: i am trying to use the webservice usergroup in sharepoint with a java app but i dont understand how to handle the return values of the methods.